# Lifetime of value

Tags: c++, c

I am confused about  the `myname` array's lifetime,is it still alive out of the `if` statement?Do we get the same answer in c and c++?

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* host;

    if (1 == argc)
    {
/*code below is copied from a book*/
        char myname[256];
        gethostname(myname, 255);
        host = myname;
/*code above is copied from a book*/
    }

    else
    {
        /*        */
    }
    printf("%s\n",host);

    return 0;
}
```

### EDIT:

The code snippet comes from the book `Begining Linux Programming 4th edition`,Chapter 15: Sockets
,I am so sorry that the author made such mistake.But the book is good in my view exclude this code.

Comment: that code comes from a book? burn it! :)

Comment: I am please you have adoptoed this: `if (1 == argc)` But do not forget the stack!

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin - Please keep that up. Using a constant on the LHS whill save you a lot of heart ache in the long run. Especiallyh when you forget a double =

Comment: @EdHeal, I'd prefer to turn up the warning level instead.

Comment: Indentation would not go amiss!

Comment: @chris - I do not understand - explain

Comment: @EdHeal, All compilers should be warning about that, at least with the right warning level. Common behaviour seems to be to warn on `if (i = 5)`, but not on `if ((i = 5))`.

Comment: @chris - it is better to be safe - Try it!

Comment: @EdHeal, GCC 4.7.2, Clang 3.2, and MSVC 11 all give the warning for single parentheses with `Wall`. However, MSVC complains about double braces as well, whereas the others silence the warning.

Comment: @EdHeal: It buys you nothing (you don't already have) and makes the code harder to read. So overall a net negative. basically its a style adaptoed a decade ago that thankfully is now defunct. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/162256/12917

Comment: @LokiAstari I learned the old style in some C books,it's better to make use of compiler.Thank you for your linking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `myname` array's lifetime[;] is it still alive out of the if statement?

**No**

```
Do we get the same answer in C and C++?
```

**Yes**

*It is ugly, bad code and has UB*, use `std::string` for `host`

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin: the code has undefined behavior which is bad, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The `myname` array is destroyed at the end of the `if`. Printing `host` at this point might just work but is **Undefined behavior**, since you are using a pointer to memory that **has been destroyed**. Its functioning is implementation dependant (and other factors).

It is identical (destroyed => undefined) in both C and C++

Comment: Not implementation dependent, but dependent on random conditions and whims. In other words, totally unpredictable.

Comment: @Potatoswatter very true, I reference the phase of the moon as having a significant effect in a previous answer of this topic.. but I expect implementation to also play a part in this yes?

Answer (score 0):

Once you leave that `if` block there are no guarantees for `myname[256]`. There is nothing in the compiler that would keep track of the fact that `host` points to `myname`, in order to "keep it alive".